# Does this electronics flow chart work as a system?

Tags: led, circuit-design, pir

I've tried to create a flow diagram of some electronics I'm trying to do for a project at home which is a motion activated light up frame (added a photo of the lights in the frame but this isn't the finished thing).

I'm not so great at circuit diagrams so made a block diagram of how things would go together. The photographs of the modules are just to clarify which module each coloured box contains. The idea is that it will be a motion sensor for a picture frame so that when someone walks past it will turn on some led lights for a set amount of time. The lights are also controllable in terms of colour/mode via rf and remote controller. (The USB doctor is just to trick the battery into not going into auto-shutdown)[image]

I just want to know if it will work? Thank you in advance for any help

Sophie

Comment: You appear to have all the ingredients for success there.  There might be some hard-to-predict compatibility issues, it’s hard to say without a datasheet for each item I don’t see any red flags.  I guess you’ve checked that each of the parts is ok on 5V?

Comment: A "flow diagram" is used to describe a sequence of actions or events. Your diagram is a block diagram but is cartoonish. The next step would be a schematic diagram showing symbols, pin numbers and wiring connections. The CircuitLab tool on the editing toolbar would allow you to create one.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post. I guess there's only one way to find out, and that's to make it. I'm pretty sure I double checked that everything will work off 5V.